# Automatically authorize swagger endpoints after login with token

Tags: php, testing, swagger, swagger-ui

My API has a login endpoint which generate a bearer token.

In Postman, I have a test script that automatically fills the token variable so I can  use my endpoints after login.

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("token", jsonData.token);
```

In Swagger, I have an "authorize" field where I can insert the token, but I want to do it automatically, in the same way I do in Postman.

Is there any way this can be achieved having in mind that the token is renewed after each login?

I'll paste below my Swagger definitions:

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                username:
                  type: string
                  example: some_user
                password:
                  type: string
                  example: some_password
  /some/endpoint:
    get:
      security:
        - bearerAuth: []
```